# Submit form using preventDefault() but keeping browser autocomplete feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am sending the data of a form using ajax, so to override the default browser behavior I am using `preventDefault()`, but I would like to keep the browser feature to remember the data typed for future autocomplete.

Is it possible to do this?

**HTML**

```
<form id="form-login" action="/padrao/Login/executaLoginAjax" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario[email]" class="entradas" placeholder="Usuário" maxlength="80" required />
    <input type="password" id="senha" name="usuario[senha]" class="entradas" placeholder="Senha" maxlength="12" required />
    <input type="submit" id="btn-logar" value="Acessar o sistema" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#form-login').submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    var dados  = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: dados,
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(json){

            if(json.sucesso){
                window.location.href = 'http://' + location.host + '/home';
            }else{
                alert('fail');
            }

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: This is not possible when using AJAX to submit a form

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, Please post your comment as answer, probably it will be the best. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... You could likely remedy this by submitting to a hidden iframe rather than using AJAX (or in addition to using ajax)

Comment: @KevinB, Can you please post an answer with an example?

Comment: I would if i knew for sure it would work. All you need is an iframe with "display: none" and a name, then add target="theiframename" to the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**

Correcting my comment from above. This is not possible when using the `preventDefault()` method when listening for a native form submission. AJAX has nothing to do with this other than being a common reason for using `preventDefault()` in the first place.

**Long answer**

As of right now the web browser's autofill or autocomplete data store is only triggered upon the form actually going through the regular submit process and triggering the serialization of data.

Using `event.preventDefault();` prevents the browser from reaching this state so it never knows to save the form data for later use.

**Possible remedies**

1. Set a `var allowNativeSubmit = false;` flag and upon successfully validating and saving the form then set `allowNativeSubmit = true;`, call the submit trigger manually and build in logic which skips the AJAX submit if this flag is true. Send the form data to a success page which does nothing with the data.
2. Every time a form is successfully submitted you can save the data into local storage and implement a jQuery UI autocomplete to simulate the browser's autofill functionality.

I've implemented #1 before and it works quite well.

**#1 example**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var allowNativeSubmit = false;

    $('#form-login').on('submit', function (e) {

        if (!allowNativeSubmit) {

            e.preventDefault();

            var formTarget = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                type: formTarget.attr('method'),
                url: formTarget.attr('action'),
                data: formTarget.serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                    if (data.sucesso) {

                        // set the action to success page
                        formTarget.attr('action', 'success.html');

                        // allow native browser submit
                        allowNativeSubmit = true;

                        // call the native browser submit
                        formTarget.submit();

                    } else {

                        alert('form validation failed!');

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue so did a bit digging: they have fixed it in google canary, schedule to release as m46 https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339927

Answer (score -1):

Just change your submit input to a regular button, and remove the form tag that's around your information.   You'll lose the ability to perform a standard submit, but if you really need to, you can readd those tags, or use a button input which could be toggled to a submit input as needed.